# Htaccess too many redirects only for wordpress blog

Tags: .htaccess

I have follwing htaccess for redirecting to www, https and index.html to /:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L]
```

On the website I use a wordpress blog on /blog, which gives this error if I try to access it:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I can fix this by swaping the rule order, first comes redirect to www and then https, but then the redirect to www does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the issue. As a programmer you really should check from time to time what people who have some access to site settings are doing.

In the wordpress login for the admin in settings -> general a custom domain was entered which was https://example.com/blog etc. which means wordpress blog redirected back to the version without www.

The fix is to add www to the wordpress setting.